# Mathematical operation on captured number that comes after a certain character in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, operation

I have a vector that has elements like this:

```
x <- c("3434/1233", "3434.332/232.2", "220.23/932.89", "908.11111/9")
```

I want to replace the numbers **after slash** with their value **multiplied by** **60**.

So the resulting vector will be:

```
x.times.sixty <- c("3434/73980", "3434.332/13932", "220.23/55973.4", "908.11111/540")
```

How can I do this?

I have tried the following which does not work:

```
gsub(x = x, pattern = "/(.*)", replacement = as.numeric('\\1' * 60))
```

Also this one:

```
gsub(x = x, pattern = "/(.*)", replacement = '\\1 * 60')
```

Comment: BTW, `9*60 = 540`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the multiplication using `gsubfn`.  Capture the numbers including the decimals at the end of the string (`([0-9.]+$)`), convert it to numeric and multiply by 60

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("([0-9.]+$)", ~ as.numeric(x)*60, x)
#[1] "3434/73980"     "3434.332/13932" "220.23/55973.4" "908.11111/540"
```

---

Or to follow the conditions correctly

```
gsubfn("\\/([0-9.]+$)", ~ paste0("/", as.numeric(x)*60), x)
#[1] "3434/73980"     "3434.332/13932" "220.23/55973.4" "908.11111/540"
```